# Get taxonomy name for the current post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am trying to get the name for a custom taxonomy assigned to the current post and in my template I have:

```
   $countries = get_terms( 'country', array('hide_empty' => false,));
      $fcountry = $countries[0]->slug;
```

However this returns the first item in the `$countries` array, instead of the term that is assigned to the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should no longer use the *legacy* function parameter format. Instead, as the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) says, use the `get_terms( $args )` format:

> Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument
> in the `$args` array:
>
> ```
> $terms = get_terms( array(
>   'taxonomy'   => 'post_tag',
>   'hide_empty' => false,
> ) );
> ```

And as for getting only the terms assigned to the current or a specific post, you can either use the `object_ids` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) with `get_terms()`, or simply use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/).

So for examples:

```php
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$countries = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'country',
    'object_ids' => $post_id, // set the object_ids
) );

// Or just use get_the_terms():
$countries = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'country' );
```